# error in file input

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

hi guys this error is rendered when i submit my form
this error is
 File 'captured_photo' exceeds the defined ini size
i made a trial to change the php.ini to 10M but still has the error

```
$uploaded_photo = $this->createElement('file', 'uploaded_photo')
                ->setLabel('upload image 2:')
                ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities())
                ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StripTags())
                //->setMaxFileSize(10 * 1024 * 1024)
                ->addFilter("StringTrim");      
                //->setRequired(TRUE);  
    $this->addElement($uploaded_photo);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several configuration directives that affect file uploads. They are

- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) (must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`)